# Interrupt R in debug mode

Tags: r

I don't know what I'm missing but I often get stucked in R debug mode, ie that from the `Browse[1]>` command prompt I can't do anything. I mean I can write things but R does not process anything. Especially, typing 'Q' to exit doesn't work. I've also tried some keyboard shortcuts (ctrl-c, alt-m as suggested in [How can I interrupt a running code in R with a keyboard command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370548/how-can-i-interrupt-a-running-code-in-r-with-a-keyboard-command) but it doesn't work)

As for now I restart R with "Session / Restart R" from RStudio, but it is not very convenient, and I am sure I am missing something.

I am using RStudio up to date on windows 7

thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you have a '+' sign instead of '>' on the left side of the command line when you had this problem? It could be possible that you were in the multi-line edit mode. Did you try pressing 'Esc'?

Comment: no there is no sign, neither ">" nor "+", there is the first line `Browse[1]>` and then I can press enter to get into a new line, but then there is no sign ; "Esc" doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you add an example function that is causing this issue for you? If you are using RStudio, you should just be able to hit the red "Stop" button in the top of the console window.

Comment: Red button is not always appearing indeed. And I am aware of the MWE, but I don't really know why it happens and as for know I don't know how to produce this easily

Comment: I guess there is something with `options(error = recover)` which I use but I'm not sure

Comment: Hmm it's hard to say what the problem is without being able to reproduce the error; I don't think the `Stop` button has ever been absent for me in debug mode. Try to make a note of it the next time it happens and add the culprit function to your question.

Comment: Please post the version of R and Rstudio you're using, and post a reproducible function which, when in debug mode, produces this hang.