# R: mapply(gsub...) gives different results than gsub(...)

Tags: r, regex, gsub, mapply

Part of my data:

```
data <- c('googel', 'googele', 'googl', 'google .de', 'google kalender',
        'google maps', 'google.ch', 'www.google.ch', 'factbook', 'facebock',
        'facebok', 'facebook', 'facebook.ch', 'facebook.com', 'facebook.de', 'facebooke')
```

I have to replace all google-like words with 'Google' and all facebook-like words with 'Facebook'. I can do this with the following code:

```
### Google coding
> google <- gsub(pattern = '.*go.*g.*l.*', replacement = 'Google', data)

### Facebook coding
> fbGoogle <- gsub(pattern = '.*fa.*bo.*k.*', replacement = 'Facebook', google)
> plyr::count(fbGoogle)
         x freq
1 Facebook    8
2   Google    8
```

I would like to do this using mapply, a vector for patterns and one for replacements. Although I use the same (quite primitive, I know) regex, I get different results than before:

```
> ### Google and Facebook togeter
> patterns <- c('.*go.*g.*l.*', '.*fa.*bo.*k.*')
> replacements <- c('Google', 'Facebook')
> fbGoogleFail <- mapply(gsub, patterns, replacements, data)
> plyr::count(fbGoogleFail)
               x freq
1        facebok    1
2       Facebook    4
3    facebook.ch    1
4    facebook.de    1
5       factbook    1
6        googele    1
7         Google    4
8     google .de    1
9    google maps    1
10 www.google.ch    1
```

Ideas where I fail here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to use `mapply`?

Comment: @Sotos: I have many more patterns to match and replace. Using two vectors is easier than repeating `gsub` dozens of times. Is there a better alternative to `mapply`? (thanks for editing my question)

Comment: @user2100721: I don't grog your answer completely. Where would I have to place `|`?

Comment: mapply is taking each data element in turn and checking for either google or facebook (not both) alternately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
gsubv <- Vectorize(function(pat,repl,data) gsub(pattern = pat,replacement = repl,x = data),vectorize.args = c("pat","repl"))
output <- gsubv(pat = patterns,repl = replacements,data = data)
output[-match(data,output)]
#[1] "Google"   "Google"   "Google"   "Google"   "Google"   "Google"   "Google"  
#[8] "Google"   "Facebook" "Facebook" "Facebook" "Facebook" "Facebook" "Facebook"
#[15] "Facebook" "Facebook"
```

Comment: I tried the first two lines and now my R Studio isn't working anymore. Looks like it's calculating, i.e. no command prompt >. But there is also no stop sign in the top right corner of the console. 

And these tips don't kill the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370548/how-can-i-interrupt-a-running-code-in-r-with-a-keyboard-command

Had to `ctrl-alt-del` it.

Comment: Thank you, it works for the sample data. I will try it on the 'real' data in the next two hours, hope it works there too (repl and patt vectors of length 27, applied to data of length 2000).