# How to exit(0) in R?

Tags: r, exit

I work in RStudio and I need to exit my code (BUT not the RStudio session) from inside a function, when it meets a specific condition, e.g. a key press. In C/c++, we use `exit(0)` function to do that. In R, if I call `quit()`, it attempts to close the entire R session for me, but I just need to stop executing current coding from inside my function.

I.e. I'm looking for function like below, which would cause the program to exit, when user enters 'q'.

```
 f <- function() {  
    if (readline("Press 'q' to exit the code: ") == 'q') 
       #I want to terminate the execution of program here
   else 
        #continue the execution of other set of commands
 }
```

Help me achieve this

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370548/how-can-i-interrupt-a-running-code-in-r-with-a-keyboard-command

Comment: Are you looking to end the R session? If so, quit()/q() are the answer: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is custom made Exit function,see if this helps

```
exit <- function() {
  .Internal(.invokeRestart(list(NULL, NULL), NULL))
                   }    
f <- function() {  
        if (readline("Press 'q' to exit the code: ") == 'q') 
           exit()

        return (1)
                }
```

Or there is another Way where you can simply stop the execution,

```
f <- function() {  
        if (readline("Press 'q' to exit the code: ") == 'q') 
                 stop("Stopping")
        return (1)
            }
```

and a rookie way to stop execution,(Not advisible)

```
         f <- function() {  
        if (readline("Press 'q' to exit the code: ") == 'q') 
                     try{x=0/0}catch{}
          return (1)
        }
```

Comment: Beautiful! - The first option is exactly what I needed.  - It nicely closes execution, without forcing me into debug mode or asking me to close the entire RStudio session.

Comment: If it works, please upvote the answer. Cheers

Comment: The `exit` function generates a non-zero exit for for me when using R3.5.1