# how can I stop a loop in R when it's already running?

Tags: r, loops

I'm running a process and I have committed a mistake in the condition so now is executing forever. How can I stop this without closing the R session?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370548/how-can-i-interrupt-a-running-code-in-r-with-a-keyboard-command

Answer (score 0):

https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/break-next/
This document should help you. I am not really sure if you mean the r-programming language but here is the way to break a loop in r:

```
x <- 1:5
for (val in x) {
   if (val == 3){
      break
   }
   print(val)
}
```

Comment: I think they mean once they’ve already written the loop, so you wouldn’t be able to add a break in.

Comment: Oh I guess the post is edited I thought he said how can I break a loop or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: Ctrl + C